# What is the easiest way to seeing if there are any matches across a few DateTime arrays?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, collections

If i have 3 DateTime lists that come from different sources

```
 List<Datetime> list1 = GetListOfDates();
 List<Datetime> list2 = GetAnotherListOfDates();
 List<Datetime> list3 = GetYetAnotherListOfDates();
```

What would be the quickest way to return a list of DateTime that exist in all 3 of the lists.   Is there some LINQ statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<DateTime> common = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<DateTime> common = new HashSet<DateTime>( list1 );
common.IntersectWith( list2 );
common.IntersectWith( list3 );
```

The `HashSet` class is more efficient for such tasks than using `Enumerable.Intersect`.

**Update:** make sure all your values are of the same `DateTimeKind`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var resultSet = list1.Intersect<DateTime>(list2).Intersect<DateTime>(list3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could intersect the lists:

```
var resultSet = list1.Intersect<DateTime>(list2);
var finalResults = resultSet.Intersect<DateTime>(list3);

foreach (var result in finalResults) {
   Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
}
```